# Google Analytics: add custom interaction field to social interaction

Tags: angular, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Sometimes I have two share buttons in my application UI (depending on state). They can share the same data, but are located in different parts of the UI. We want to analyze from which button (part of UI) the share was executed. I was hoping to use the `fieldsObject` field for this part, as shown in the [documentation:](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/social-interactions)

`ga('send', 'social', [socialNetwork], [socialAction], [socialTarget], [fieldsObject]);`

However, all the examples I can find only utilize the three first fields, typically something like:

`ga('send', {
    hitType: 'social',
    socialNetwork: 'Twitter',
    socialAction: 'share',
    socialTarget: 'http://www.example.com/article-01'
});`

Also, I don't understand what the documentation means by:

> "Note that as with all send commands, the fields passed in the
>   convenience parameters may also be specified in the `fieldsObject`."

I thouhght maybe I was utilizing the "convenience parameter".
My sharing code (from an Angular service):

`reportShare(media:string, context: string) {
    let pageUrl: string = this.sanitizeURL();
    ga('send', {
        hitType: 'social',
        socialNetwork: media,
        socialAction: 'share',
        socialTarget: pageUrl,
        fieldsObject: context
    });
}`

My Google Analytics Debugger says:

`VM5405 analytics_debug.js:16 Running command: ga("send", {hitType: "social", socialNetwork: "Twitter", socialAction: "share", socialTarget: "/find/1160", fieldsObject: "machine"})`

But then:
`Set called on unknown field: "fieldsObject".`

And as we can see from the the rest, "fieldsObject" is not passed along:

`adSenseId        (&a)   1505578412
anonymizeIp      (&aip) 1
apiVersion       (&v)   1
clientId         (&cid) 1703756191.1573561297
encoding         (&de)  UTF-8
hitType          (&t)   social
javaEnabled      (&je)  0
language         (&ul)  en-us
location         (&dl)  http://localhost/find/1160
screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit
screenResolution (&sr)  1680x1050
socialAction     (&sa)  share
socialNetwork    (&sn)  Twitter
socialTarget     (&st)  /find/1160
title            (&dt)  This pagetitle
trackingId       (&tid) UA-*********-1
viewportSize     (&vp)  1680x916`

Is there a way to pass along the fieldsObject with my context string using social interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for replying!
Firstly, I've moved from analytics.js to gtag.js.

I created Custom Dimensions in the GA interface:
*Admin > Custom Definitions > Custom Dimensions*, and gave it the name "Share Context". Custom Dimensions for gtag is [documentet here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets).

I then update my js calls:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-**********-*', {
    'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'context'},
    'custom_map': {'dimension2': 'context'},
    'anonymize_ip': true,
    'allow_ad_personalization_signals': false
 });
```

In my reporting service I then can call:

```
reportShare(media:string, context: string) {
    gtag('event', 'Sharing Context', {
        'dimension2': context,
        'event_category': 'social',
        'event_label': media,
        'value': this.sanitizedURL
    });
}
```

Finally, under *Acquisition > Social > Plugins* I can access my custom dimension from *Social Entity > Secondary Dimensions > Custom Dimension > Share Context* (which is the name you provide when creating the custom dimension).

More about [reporting non-standard data as custom dimensions & metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be naming that fieldObjects.
The documentation state that fieldObjects are the ones that are not passed along in the fields signature this means any other fields reamining that you want to sent. The documentation states about fieldObjects:

> An object for specifying any remaining values not specified in any of
>   the fields parameters.
>
> If a field is set in both a fields parameter and fieldsObject, the
>   value in fieldsObject will be used.

So I think that it should be:

```
ga('send', {
        hitType: 'social',
        socialNetwork: media,
        socialAction: 'share',
        socialTarget: pageUrl
    }, 
    {
        anyOtherLabel: value
    }
  );
```

Documentation reference for ga command and more examples could be checked here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/command-queue-reference#method-details

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

It's a bit hard to check as it takes a while for the social data to display in GA. But will I be able to have this custom value show up on the Social Plugins page? Do I have to customize the view (if possible) to have it display?

Comment: By Social Plugins page do you mean the Analytics views of Social Interactions?

Comment: I will assume that yes, they should appear also there.
Please edit your comment and delete your tag from it as anyone could get it

Comment: Thanks! I had to modify it in a new comment as the edit possibility was lost:

Yes, located at Acquisition > Social > Plugins. But I had to redesign it a bit: ```reportShare(media:string, context: string) { 
let pageUrl: string = this.sanitizeURL(); 
ga('set', 'dimension2', context); ga('send', { 
hitType: 'social', 
socialNetwork: media, 
socialAction: 'share', socialTarget: pageUrl }); }```

And then update the tag:
```config: gtag('config', 'UA-*********-*', { 
'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'context'}, 
'custom_map': {'dimension2': 'context'}, 
})```

Comment: Please, once you tested and see that the events are appearing under the quoted location let us know, so I can update the answer too for everyone

Comment: I had to change my entire approach. Posted my working solution above.
Thanks for your input!